# When to use constructors in React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I always write React code, particularly in ES6 Classes. But my question is, when do we use `constructor(props)` in React Components? Does the `constructor(props)` line has something to do with the rendering of the component together with its props?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<strike>The accepted answer is incorrect (perhaps just a misuse of the word "render").</strike>

<strike>As I explain in my comment on it</strike> the constructor of a React component is executed once the first time the component is mounted, or instantiated. It is never called again in subsequent renders.

Typically the constructor is used to set-up a component's internal `state`, for example:

```
constructor () {
  super()
  this.state = {
    // internal state
  }
}
```

Or if you have the class property syntax available (e.g. [via Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-syntax-class-properties)) you can forgo declaring a constructor if all you are using it for is to initialise the state:

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    // internal state
  }
}
```

---

> Does the constructor(props) line has something to do with the rendering of the component together with its props?

The constructor does not directly dictate what is rendered by a component.

What is rendered by a component is defined by the return value of its `render` method.